# "ask somebody about something" in French

Tags: prépositions

I'm wondering how to translate correctly to French a simple sentence:

> ask somebody (a question) about something

What is correct?

> demander qqn **de** qqch
>
> demander qqn **sur** qqch

For example:

- "I want to ask about your holidays" = "Je demande de/sur/... tes vacances"
- "I want to ask you about train tickets" = "J'aimerais te demander de/sur/... des billets de train"

Comment: Not exactly your question, but related : "to ask somebody about somebody [else]" is "demander à quelqu'un des nouvelles de quelqu'un [d'autre]". If the person you're asking is the same as the person you're asking about, it becomes "demander à quelqu'un de ses nouvelles".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Poser une question :

- *Je demande **à** Jean s'il peut me prêter son livre*

Se renseigner :

- *Je lui demande **comment** il a passé ses vacances*

Demander un objet, un service :

- *Je lui demande **de** me prêter son livre*

Demander quelque chose à quelqu'un sur un tiers (ou sur ce qu'il peut me faire connaître) :

- *Je lui demande des renseignements **sur** la situation en Orient*

Demander quelque chose  pour (à la place de) quelqu'un :

- *Je demande des jouets **pour** Alice*

Demander pour obtenir un objet :

- *Je demande une carte **pour** avoir un meilleur jeu*

Demander un renseignement sur un point précis (raccourci familier) :

- *Je demande l'horaire **pour** Nice (du train qui va partir pour Nice)*

Demander en tenant compte du contexte :

- *Je lui demande **avec** précaution, de me parler de ses problèmes*

Demander une localisation :

- *Je lui demande **où** se trouve la Place des Vosges*

Demander une réponse :

- *Je demande **quelle** est la solution*

Comment: Votre exemple avec «demander **pour**» emploie, il me semble, le sens de «à sa place» de *pour*, mais est-ce que *pour*,  dans son  sens de «en ce qui concerne (qqch.)», peut marcher avec *demander* pour capter un peu l’idée de «about» en anglais?  Voilà mon exemple très maladroit (et peut-être même très incorrect?!?): «J’ai demandé à la patronne pour (en ce qui concerne/au sujet de/ à propos de [=’about’?]) la courte durée prévue pour nos vacances l’année prochaine.»  où *pour* veut dire,  à peu prés, «pour savoir plus au sujet de … .» Merci!

Comment: @PapaPoule  ... est-ce que les exemples ajoutés répondent à votre interrogation ?

Comment: *Si*, *comment*, *où* et *quelle* sont simplement des questions indirectes. Il y a plusieurs autres pronoms interrogatifs similaires (*quand*, *à qui*, *pourquoi*, *de quoi*, etc.).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez J'ai essayé de donner quelques exemples d'utilisation en fonction de l'intention de la demande, je suis preneur d'exemples complémentaires pour étoffer ma réponse.

Comment: Oui, merci, et je le prends comme confirmation que mon exemple avec *pour* (dans son sens de «en ce qui concerne») placé juste après «demander» n’est pas seulement maladroit, mais incorrect aussi!

Answer (score 2):

To ask about something that is a general proposition:  holidays (or day, exam, etc.) in French is: vouloir savoir + comment + se passer [quelque chose].

This is not demander quelque chose or poser une question.

For events or things like exams or holidays: **Je voulais te demander comment se sont passées tes vacances.
Je voulais te demander comment s'est passé ton examen.**

For people: **Comment + aller + [person or persons]**

**Je voulais te demander comment allaient tes parents.**
**Je voulais vous demander comment va votre épouse.**

Answer (score 1):

ask somebody (a question) about something =

> demander à quelqu'un quelque chose
>
> poser à quelqu'un une question sur quelque chose

Comment: I'd like to add that the order here isn't important : "demander quelque chose à quelqu'un" / "poser une question sur quelque chose à quelqu'un" also work.

Comment: @Pwassonne , oui, c'était juste pour respecter le texte d'origine. demander quelque chose à quelqu'un est bcp plus courant.